# Read the last line of output of a bash command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to read the current line of output from a bash command.
I know I could get this with `cmd | tail -1`, but I want to run this as a seperate command (tint2 executable) as a sort of progress meter.

For example:

I have a python program that outputs `Downloaded x out of y` as it downloads images, and I want to get the output as a shell variable.

Or:

Maybe I'm running `pacman -Syy` and I want

`extra                    420.6 KiB   139K/s 00:09 [#####-----------------]  24%`

Is this possible?

Edit: Something is running in the terminal. I want a command that outputs the last output of the command in the previous terminal, maybe inputting a pid.

Comment: You can assign the output of your command to a variable: `var=$(cmd | tail -1)`

Comment: @codeforester I want to run a separate command

Comment: There is [`pv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pv.1.html) if you don't want to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample code that, even though not working, illustrates what you mean by "I want to run a separate command"?

Comment: I added an edit @Fred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tee` to write things to the terminal and some logfile.
Lets say your python program looks like this

```
function mypython {
   for i in 10 30 40 50 80 90 120 150 160 180 190 200; do
      (( progress = (100 * i + 50) / 200 ))
      printf "extra   xx Kb, total %-3d of 200 (%d %%)\n" $i ${progress}
      sleep 1
   done
}
```

You can redirect or `tee` the output to a tmp file:
(mypython > /tmp/robert.out) &
or
(mypython | tee /tmp/robert.out) &

In another window you can get the last line with
tail -1 /tmp/robert.out

When you only want to see a progress, you might want something like to get the last line to overwrite the previous one.

```
mypython | while read -r line; do
   printf "Progress of mypython: %s\r" "${line}"
done
```

When this is what you want you might want to change your python program

```
  printf "...\r" ...
```